# How to read Json file on Colab

Tags: json, google-colaboratory

I imported a json file from  google drive to Colab like this

downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':'XXX'})
downloaded.GetContentFile('All_Beauty.json')

and when I try reading the file with

```
import pandas as pd
beauty_df = pd.read_json('All_Beauty.json')
beauty_df.head()
```

I get this error:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-1acb00f4feed> in <module>()
----> 1 beauty_df = pd.read_json('All_Beauty.json')
      2 beauty_df.head()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
   1087         if orient == "columns":
   1088             self.obj = DataFrame(
-> 1089                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
   1090             )
   1091         elif orient == "split":
```

`ValueError: Trailing data`

Any idea of what is going wrong? Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have several lines in your json file.
you probably need to use the `lines` argument:

```
beauty_df = pd.read_json('All_Beauty.json', lines=True)
```